# Correlation ID pattern for correlate requests of same flow

Tags: logging, correlation, monolithic

I have a web application that has some multi page flows where users populate different pieces of informations and being able to move back & forward. In the backend, we need to track all these endpoint requests logs and to be able to relate all log entries to a single flow.

I was thinking about the correlation ID pattern, but that one is often mentioned in a microservices context with asynchronous messaging, which isn't the case here. Is there something equivalent to correlation ID for standard monolithic applications?